# React Native application deployment

Tags: react-native

I have already developed a React native application on my mac book, this is myfirst application. I want to deploy it to iPhone so that I can test it. I don't want to put it on appstore yet.  I am not sure how to compile the application and get it ready to put it on iPhone. I tried this web site
https://www.diawi.com/, but not sure which .ipa or a.pk file, I need to upload. I can also try using expo, but not sure how to use it. Can anyone give me step by step instruction on how to upload this application on iPhone.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Expo is quite simple. You just launch the dev server on your pc and scan the QR code. The app will run on your smartphone. (at least that's how it works on android).

Comment: How did you made your app? if you use `create-react-app` then you use expo. If you are using `react-native-init` then you can't probably put on your iPhone without apple account.

Comment: I used react-native init. I do have apple account, but dont want to spend 99 dollars to publish the application on  app store. I just want to give the phone to my manager to review the application.

Comment: For `react-native-init` you can't **probably** use expo. 
You would need an Apple Developer account to test your app on your phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For iPhone

For **`react-native-init`** you will probably need Apple developer account to test your app on your phone

Since you are using `react-native-init`, You should checkout this article by Facebook

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

In the second point, it says *Register for an Apple developer account if you don't have one yet*

For **`create-react-native-app`** you need to do following

Download [expo client from App store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/expo-client/id982107779?mt=8)

Scan the QR code expo generate when you run your app using terminal (**`npm run start`** in terminal )

**Note:** Both Laptop and your phone should be on the same network

According to [this thread](http://%20https://forums.expo.io/t/react-native-init-expo-sdk/1903), You can't use expo with `react-native-init` but alternatively you can create an expo project using `create-react-native-app` and then copy, paste files from your `init` project

### For Android

For running your App on Android, You can directly generate/build an `apk`, send it to your device and just open it to see how it works (In Android you don't need a console or developer account to run your app)

Again, Open this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

And click on Android Tab to see how you can **generate an Apk**

Comment: can you give me more details or point to the web site that can more details

Comment: Yeah, Expo is good, you just need to spend 5 mins to deploy your app onto iOS device

Comment: @Anjali expo won't work with `react-native-init` though you can start with `create-react-native-app` and then copy paste your code.

Comment: I tried using expo and installed npm install -g create-react-native-app. I successfully send the link to my iphone, but now i am getting an error saying "There was a problem loading the requested app. It looks like you may be using the LAN URL. make sure your device is on the same network as the server or try using  a tunnel." I am on the same network

Comment: successfully send the link to your phone? You mean you scanned it through camera? or did you manually enter the address? Just in case, You need to open your in-built camera app on iPhone and scan it

Comment: no, when I did npm start, i was prompted to enter "s" to send the app URL to my phone number. when I entered "s", it asked me for my phone number. As soon as I entered my phone number, It texted me the URL that  was a URL exp://10.21....  This is iPhone. I think, I need to scan the QR code for android

Comment: I don't usually work with expo since it increases the file size exponentially but when I used it once, As soon as I did `npm run start` it created a QR code (or probably by pressing q should show you a QR code). All you need to do it from there is scan it via your camera app and it should prompt you to open expo app. Alternatively, You can ask it as another question on Stackoverflow if google wasn't able to help you

Comment: expo link is working now. Thank you for all your help!!